# Node based GUI (Cocoa)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, user-interface

I am in the process of starting a project and whilst the logic part is relatively simple for me to mull through I am not very experienced with creating GUIs.

If you are not familiar with node based workflow here are a few examples

Nuke (The Foundry)

[image]

Max/MSP (Cycling 74)

[image]

SoftImage (AutoDesk)

[image]

The problems I have is where to start, What kind of object should I use to encapsulate the node gui? Or How would I go about making custom GUI elements that are click-drag/movable within a workspace? Are there any Books you recommend or anything you can link me too that would be able to get me up to speed.

Thank You

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "node GUI." Do you mean a tree/outline? If so, see NSOutlineView and NSOutlineViewDataSource in the API. If not, you're going to have to describe your goal a lot more clearly.

Comment: I did want to but i was hindered at giving examples with pictures so I edited them out and went on a thread answering mission :) 

That should make it clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your node view will derive from NSView, and I imagine that you'll want to use CALayers for your nodes.

You may find it helpful to look at some opensource Cocoa frameworks that implement custom views. Two that spring to mind are TwUI and GCDrawKit. Neither are a drop-in solution for what you want but they should give you an idea about how to architect complex custom views in Cocoa.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for, I have been trying to look up custom views to see how they are put together. Thank you for the links to the frameworks I will have a look at them in a sec. Out of interest are they in obj-c, c or c++?

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you use interface builder and the AppKit framework. A good introductory book is [Cocoa Programming for Mac Os X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503619)

Comment: Thank you is there anything a little more specific I can research, I do have that book but im still a little stuck.

from what I assume, you make a custom object using NSViews but the interaction is the part i have the main issue with.

Comment: Yes, for interactions you use IBOutlet and IBACtion. There are many beginning guides here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Guides

Comment: Thank you, I am obviously overlooking something very simple. I am not that new to cocoa I understand the principals involved but i lack familiarity with the objects/views I will get back to reading the docs. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This answer is so generic it doesn't deserve to be here.

Comment: Are you serious? It's a generic answer to a generic question, and it's the correct answer, that's how you make guis with Cocoa.

Comment: It is and was a bit too generic I am afraid. It didn't really come close to answering my question.